# What is the function of the EGR vacuum delay valve?

Tags: egr, sienna

My 2008 Toyota Sienna has an EGR vaccum delay valve bolted to the assembly of a motor mount under the engine.

The vacuum lines cracked and the ol' cut-and-reattach isn't an option for me in the moment because there is just no way to get the vacuum hoses on and the fastener holding the valve on won't loosen without breaking the assembly.

My only option until fixing it for real is to cap off the vacuum port.

I'm just wondering what this thing is even supposed to do since I've just disabled it. So far no codes or anything.

[Exhaust Gas Recirculation (EGR) Vacuum Delay Valve](https://parts.toyota.com/p/Toyota_2008_Sienna/Exhaust-Gas-Recirculation-EGR-Vacuum-Delay-Valve-DUTY-VACUUM-SWITCHING-VACUUM-SWITCHING/62987084/9091012204.html)

Answer (score 0):

I´ts one way to ECU control the exhoust gas circulation more accured.
If jou bypass the solenoid the EGR is still working .no fault codes.